# Prevent data duplication with condition

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to setup a data duplication check on a text box which is used to input serial numbers.

If the entered serial number is already found in the database, it should call a MsgBox to alert the user before clearing the value in the text box.

However, if the entered serial number contains "RW", the check should be disabled.

```
Private Sub Serial_Number_AfterUpdate()
Dim NewSerialNumber As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String

NewSerialNumber = Me.Serial_Number.Value
stLinkCriteria = "[Serial_Number] = " & "'" & NewSerialNumber & "'"
If Me.Serial_Number = DLookup("[Serial_Number]", "Esagon_End", stLinkCriteria) Then
    MsgBox "This serial number, " & NewSerialNumber & ", has already been entered into the database." _
            & vbCr & vbCr & "Please check the serial number again.", vbI, "Duplicate information"
    Me.Undo
End If

End Sub
```

If this cannot be done with VBA I'm open to other methods like queries. Thank you.

Comment: "delete the serial number in the text box" and "the data duplication would be disabled" seem the same to me. So, try to rephrase the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at what you have asked, I think this is what you are looking for. If it isn't then leave a comment and I'll try to update my answer.

```
Private Sub Serial_Number_AfterUpdate()

'If it doesn't contain "RW"
If InStr(Me.Serial_Number, "RW") = 0 Then
    'If serial number not in the database
    If DCount("*", "Esagon_End", "Serial_Number = '" & Me.Serial_Number & "'") > 0 Then
        'Alert user and blank the text box
        Call MsgBox("The serial number " & Me.Serial_Number & " is already in the database." _
                    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Please check the serial number you are entering.", _
                    vbInformation, "Duplicate Serial")
        Me.Serial_Number = ""
    End If
End If

End Sub
```